# Login page theme

Tags: 7, theming, users

I have created my own theme in drupal 7 using only `page.tpl.php` as I am happy to use the same template for every node/page.

When visiting *mysite.com/?q=user/login* every sidebar-navbar from my theme appears there as expected and I would like to remove them from the login form though I really want to avoid creating the login template *page--user--login.tpl.php*. I was thinking of using the default body class somehow

`<body class="html not-front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-user page-user-login">
<body class="maintenance-page in-maintenance no-sidebars">`

`no-sidebars` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The sidebar is appearing as there will be some content(blocks) displayed on it.

So, in blocks section, you need to configure those blocks listed there, and in **Show block on specific pages** section, select "***All pages except those listed***" and add *user/login* in the textarea below.

Comment: Thank you. In every block I tried selecting **All pages except those listed** and adding user/login with no results. The sidebar has to have a special <div> id or class? Do I have to follow any rule with the names in the .info file? 
regions[header]              = Header
regions[navigation]          = Navigation bar
regions[sidebar_first]       = Sidebar first
regions[sidebar_second]      = Sidebar second

I am using

regions[side-menu] = Side Menu
regions[navbar] = Navigation Bar
regions[content] = Content
regions[col2-1] = 2 Columns Number 1
regions[col2-2] = 2 Columns Number 2

Comment: If that doesn't work, why did you accept the answer?

Comment: Somebody edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have temporary solved the issue by using a little bit of css to hide the sidebar and, to eliminate the html, the following:

`<?php if ($logged_in): ?><div class="mysidebar"></div><?php endif; ?>`

I am not sure if there is a way drupal will eliminate the side bar when there is not block on them.

Furthermore, I leave this here so I hope it is helpful to somebody

> General utility variables:
>
> - $base_path: The base URL path of the Drupal installation. At the very
>     least, this will always default to /.
> - $directory: The directory the template is located in, e.g. modules/system or themes/bartik.
> - $is_front: TRUE if the current page is the front page.
> - $logged_in: TRUE if the user is registered and signed in.
> - $is_admin: TRUE if the user has permission to access administration pages.